# Select and jQuery targeting on Ajax generated pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Select box on an AJAX generated page, which is like this

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
   <option value="https://xy.com/accessories.html?dir=asc&amp;limit=15&amp;order=name">Name</option>
   <option value="https://xy.com/accessories.html?dir=asc&amp;limit=15&amp;order=price" selected="selected">Price</option>
 </select>
```

And I want to make a jQuery code that scrolls back to the top of the page when the select is changes (but of course to do the default javascript function also). I tried this script, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
jQuery("body").on( "change", ".sort-by select, .limiter select", function(){
  jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});
```

Any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to add the change listener on the select element itself (not on the body).  It must be done after it has been loaded in the DOM by your ajax call.

```
$('.sort-by select, .limiter select').on('change', function() { /* your code here */ });
```

Ideally, your selector would be precise enough to target only the select boxes within the new elements that your Ajax call has inserted in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks it, works on the first time, but not on AJAX refresh - and I can't get in to the AJAX code itself, since it is done in prototype. Any idea, how I can bind the jQuery to it for all the changes?

Comment: @Gas I don't know of your project's architecture, but you can most certainly bind listeners to your inserted content using a callback from the Prototype API.  For example, the Ajax.Updater class from Prototype has an "onComplete" event that is triggered after the content has been updated.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Prototype at all :-( Any chances to get jQuery to catch some prototype actions, or by content generation it performs?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  If your project is using Prototype to do its Ajax, you're most likely better off learning a bit about Prototype.  In this particular case, you'll probably need to find the bit of js code that makes the Ajax call using prototype and add some event-binding code on a successful return from that ajax call.